# Why natbib package can not find author?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a .bib file as following:

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 

@book{marcu2000theory,
    Author = {Marcu, Daniel},
    Date-Added = {2013-02-12 04:56:47 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-02-12 04:56:47 +0000},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {The theory and practice of discourse parsing and summarization},
    Year = {2000}}
```

My Latex file:

```
\documentclass{article} % For LaTeX2e
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{T}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cite{marcu2000theory}
\citeauthor{marcu2000theory}

\bibliography{DPSurvey}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

However, I always got the warning:

```
Author undefined for citation`marcu2000theory' (natbib) on page 1
```

Could someone point out the mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `natbib`'s replacement of `plain style`, `plainnat.bst`. And to have numerical citations, use the `numbers` options.

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Comment: actually, it seems not need the numbers options. I now can work well. Thanks!